# App pausing but not getting an error after running a clean

Tags: ios, freeze

I have no idea what is after going wrong but I'll state the events that happened before the error occurred

1: App was running fine as I was adding functionality.

2: I noticed that one of the view controllers was not showing the correct version but an older one. (I had added in a segmented control and it wasn't showing up)

3: I tried to uninstall the from my phone and build it again but it was still showing the old controller

4: I tried cleaning the project to recompile everything, after this step the application started to give me this problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYemK.png

Some extra information:

1: This error occurs on the black screen before any view controllers load

2: The view controller I was working on was not the first view controller (so I do not think that it is the problem)

3: The main view controller has not been changed in days and was working perfectly since it was finished

I have absolutely no idea what is going wrong, and help would be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE 1**

New error message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/buXXt.png

**UPDATE 2**

Screenshot of storyboard and a finder window that opened when I clicked "show in finder on the storyboard". This would lead me to believe that it does know where the file is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1hFZ.png

Answer (score 1):

You've (probably accidentally) set a breakpoint at the `return UIApp...`-line.

You can identify a breakpoint by it's blue color at the left of a line. If it's activated, it's dark blue, else it's light blue. You can just drag it either to the trash can or somewhere else in your window to completely delete the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

your app is getting crashed due to exception check the pannel `objc_exception_throw`

add exception breakpoint and you'll get the line of code where your app is crashing

Comment: It's saying that it cannot find my storyboard

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something is broken, and throws an exception.  You're just seeing the exception being caught.

The way to investigate what is throwing is to add an exception breakpoint.  Go to the breakpoints list and hit +, choose exception breakpoint and leave it at all.  This should give you a breakpoing at the point where the except is being thrown.

As to what is happening.  You had an app that ran with an old VC, you deleted the app and re-installed and now it crashes, so best guess is that your old version had the VC, but new one doesn't.  Sounds like a missing xib or storyboard.  It clearly isn't missing from the project, as you'd see that immediately, but check for target membership, changed name or localization problems.

Comment: I have done this and now it is telling me that it cannot find my MainStoryboard file

This is an application that I have written from scratch a few days ago, I haven't deleted and reinstalled anything :S

Comment: Glad adding the exception breakpoint helped.

I'm not sure why renaming would help, maybe that reset the target membership or something.

Comment: Yeah I know right? I figured I'd give it a try since the storyboard was showing up in the storyboard. But I wouldn't have caught it if it wasn't for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by renaming the storyboard to MainStoryboard1 and changing the target in

project > target > summary > iphone/ipod deployment